# Change device name on EXIF file

Tags: custom-roms, camera, motorola

Recently I've been flashing some ROM s on my Moto X, and I noticed that the EXIF data from photos show my device name as: Phone. How can I change this information on the system so it saves correctly my phone name?

PS. Changing build.prop doesn't change anything.
Thanks for any help!